# Why the constant curvature curves on plane don't contains general hyperbola?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, curves, curvature

For a curve $y=f(x)$, the curvature is 
$$
k=\frac{|y''|}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}
$$
If the curvature is a constant, there are 3 cases
\begin{align}
\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}=0  \tag{1}\\
\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{R}   \tag{2}      \\
\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}=-\frac{1}{R}   \tag{3}
\end{align}
where $R>0$. Obviously, the solution of (1) is line. I solution  (2) and (3), the solution of (2) and (3) always be 
$$
R^2=(x-C_2R)^2+(y-C_2R)^2  \\
R^2=(x-C_2R)^2-(y-C_2R)^2 
$$
they are circle and hyperbola. But no matter how I  solute it , I can't get the hyperbola like
$$
R^2=-(x-C_2R)^2+(y-C_2R)^2 
$$
Besides, there is not more general hyperbola which focus is not at x-axis and y-axis. But obviously, the curvature should be a intrinsic concept, so the general hyperbola should be contained in the solution of (1),(2),(3). How to explain it ?

In fact, I think it is because I assume $y=f(x)$, but I can't think it out.

Comment: You should check your calculations more carefully in the case of the hyperbola. Neither $R^2=(x-C_2R)^2-(y-C_2R)^2$ nor $R^2=-(x-C_2R)^2+(y-C_2R)^2$ has constant curvature, as you can tell by actually *looking* at a hyperbola.

Comment: @LeeMosher   Thanks,  I mistake a sign, there is not hyperbola.